# Port 3306 appears to be closed on my Ubuntu server

Tags: server, mysql

I have two [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) servers, and both have [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) installed, one for testing and one for development. One of my servers won't let me connect from outside. With the user;

> 'mytestuser'@'%'

According to [an open port finder](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), port 3306 for the offending server appears to be closed. I have C++ and Java programs of my own listening on arbitrary ports without any issues. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Ubuntu installed is Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab072.10 x86_64)

### Results of `netstat -tuple` on each server

#### Offending server

```
tcp        0      0 localhost.lo:submission *:*                     LISTEN      root       39967664    -
```

#### Working server

```
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN      mysql      1847519288  -
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The problem was that the server was listening internally only.

Removing the line `bind-address 127.0.0.1` from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` solved the issue.

Newer versions of Ubuntu (≥16.04) may have this line in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

Comment: This worked for me. Note the correct filename is `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, not `/etc/mysql/my.conf`.

Comment: I changed my bind-address to match the server's external ip address and that worked for me.

Comment: Remove the line completly and the server will listen to ALL interfaces

Comment: You saved my day, been trying to solve this issue for a couple weeks, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

My suggestion, if you are sure that the ports are closed (I find it weird for a VPS to have that port closed) is to change the configuration file of MySQL to use another.

Simply open the configuration file in the terminal, `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf`, and look for the `[mysqld]` section. In it, look for the line that reads `port            = 3306`. Change it to another port not used and save the file.

Then simply either restart the VPS or restart the service, like `sudo service mysql restart`.

Just to note that, if the file `mysql.conf` is not in the one I mentioned above it can be in this other places:

```
/etc/my.conf
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.conf
```

And if the `service` command does not work, then do this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

If the problem persists then in my case I would check [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) (I would actually delete everything in iptables just to start fresh if this could be an option) or any other firewall-enabled option.

Since they are VPS, I would also check the VPS Control Panel to see if it has any option that can block ports.

Apart from that, I would run `nmap` on the VPS to see what ports you have opened. You need to run it from outside the VPS to see what ports they have opened.

`netstat -tuplen` is also a good idea to see what opened ports you have on the server and which ones are in LISTEN mode.

Comment: Hey, I tried it on another port and its still miss behaving, I also tried 'iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport _PORT_ -j ACCEPT' but no luck :( .. edit im not o eth0 .. might stil have hope.

Comment: @Andy Updated answer to include some more suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Luis I will look into this.

Comment: I have updated the results of netstat -tuple to the question. Looks like there is an issue here.

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this by changing `bind-address 127.0.0.1` to `bind-address 0.0.0.0` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` so that MySQL listens on all ports.

Also, I set up a mysql user account to be used remotely. For more details see [Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24171107/132374).

Answer (score 10):

I use this method:

```
sudo ufw status
sudo ufw allow XXXX/tcp
# use a port other than the default/predictable 3306
# work outside, and close the door when you are done
sudo ufw deny XXXX/tcp
```

No need to change other configuration files, and no extra ports opened by default.

Comment: `sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp` I tried to edit but wouldn't let me

Answer (score 2):

It may happen that your configuration is in the directory `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, verify if that is not the case.

Comment: I was trying to figure it out for like three hours before I saw this, thanks!